# Merging multiple dummies with same name into one

Tags: r, merge, data-cleaning, dummy-variable

My problem goes as follows: I have dummified multiple columns:

| type 1 | type 2 |
| --- | --- |
| fire | leaf |
| leaf | fire |

into

| type 1$fire | type$leaf | type 2$fire | type2$leaf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I've already removed the first part of the columns' name

| fire | leaf | fire | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

How can i get this result?

| fire | leaf |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

I have used fastDummies to create the dummies
thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which technology do you use?

Comment: right know i've tried to creeate a loop but i'm not a good programmer and i don't really know what to do

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("type_1    type_2
fire    leaf
leaf    fire")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  name    fire  leaf
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 type_1     1     1
2 type_2     1     1


df %>% 
  select(-name) # If you don't want the name column
```

Comment: it didn't work, it returned all na. i don't have just these two observations and i have 50 columns, maybe i should have specified better the problem

Comment: @stefanopanero Then post dput(head(df, 20)) here so it can be tested.